# Button that saves file with name specified in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that has a button:

[image]
This button runs this script:

```
function exportarPlanilha() {
  const exportSheetName = 'Demonstrativo';  // Please set the target sheet name.

  // 1. Copy the active Spreadsheet as a tempora Spreadsheet.
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().copy('tmp');

  // 2. Convert the formulas to the texts.
  const targetRange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(exportSheetName).getDataRange();
  targetRange.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});

  // 3. Delete the sheets except for a sheet you want to export.
  spreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    if (exportSheetName != sheet.getName()) spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet)
  });

  // 4. Retrieve the blob from the export URL.
  const id = spreadsheet.getId();
  const xlsxBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=${id}&exportFormat=xlsx`, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}}).getBlob();

  // 5. Crete the blob as a file.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CLIENT_FOLDER").next();

  folder.createFile(xlsxBlob.setName(`${exportSheetName}.xlsx`));
  // DriveApp.createFile....
  // 6. Delete the temporate Spreadsheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
}
```

This script exports the sheet to a folder in my Google Drive (hypothetically specified in the script as "CLIENT_FOLDER"). However, it is saving the file as "Demonstrativo.xlsx" ('exportSheetName') and I need it to save the file according to the name specified in cell B97 (in this example it is "this_should_be_the_filename", but in reality it is a formula that concatenates many variables into a string). How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value of the cell first:

```
var filename = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B97").getValue()+".xslx";

folder.createFile(xlsxBlob.setName(filename));
```